# What is the best way to run a script block in puppet exec?

Tags: exec, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Executing simple commands is pretty straight forward. But what is the best way to write, if the command is a script block instead of a one-liner, e.g.:

```
exec {
    command => 'for i in vars
                do
                    echo $i
                    more-statements
                done'; 
}
```

A couple of ways that I can think of are:

- Write the script block with proper escaping to get it to work (not a very tidy option)
- Write the script block in file.sh and execute it in command

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to write it as a script block, I generally do it in the way you described:

```
exec { 'Multi line exec':
    command => "source foo.sh
echo 'bar'
touch /var/tmp/baz
",
    path => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin',
    provider => 'shell',
}
```

Generally, I advise against doing this, because it becomes a little complicated with escaping things (and the difference between a puppet usage of `$` variables and actual shell `$` variables...

Depending on the complexity of the script, and if you want to run it with tools other than Puppet, I'd generally create it as a file-on-disk with a `file` type, then have an exec run the scripts.

Or even better, split the shells parts into separate exec resources with dependencies and unless parameters.

Comment: It looks like you have mismatching " and ' in there